# CMD - DISM - получение строки с прогрессом операции

Tags: cmd, vb.net, visual-basic

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, почему в вывод не попадает строка с прогрессом и есть ли способ ее получить?**

**Запуск CMD**

```
Dim PRS_START_INFO As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo
PRS_START_INFO.FileName = "Cmd.exe"
PRS_START_INFO.Arguments = "/c Dism.exe /Mount-Wim /WimFile:C:\W7\ggg\install.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\WIM"
PRS_START_INFO.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
PRS_START_INFO.UseShellExecute = False
PRS_START_INFO.CreateNoWindow = True
PRS_START_INFO.RedirectStandardOutput = True
PRS_START_INFO.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866)
PRS_START_INFO.Verb = "runas"
Dim iPR as Process = Process.Start(PRS_START_INFO)
EX_IM = iPR
iPR.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

**Вывод**

```
Public WithEvents EX_IM As Process

Private Sub EX_IM_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles EX_IM.OutputDataReceived
    On Error Resume Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\1.txt", e.Data & vbCrLf, True)
End Sub
```

**Результат**

[image: Прогресс операции]
[image: Результат операции]

Comment: У вас перехватывается стандартный вывод, но строка прогресса скорее всего выводится не через стандартный вывод, а средствами WinAPI в конкретное место консоли.

Comment: insolor, спасибо за подсказку, попробую покопать в этом направлении